# Update a table column with some values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help or guidance on this.

I have this situation where I don't have a primary key in the first table:

```
County, 
Gender,
EconomyName, 
HighestEducation, 
HighestEducationCount,
EconomyCount
```

In a second table, I have

```
County, 
Gender, 
HighestEducation, 
HighestEducationCount
```

I want to update the first table (`HighestEducaiion, HighestEducationCount`) from the second table value.

How to do this without a key? Here is the sample data, EconStat,EduStatu is blank in table 1.

```
County  Year    Gender  AgeDetails      EconStat    EducStatu   AgeCnt  EconCnt EduCnt
Carlow  2006    Male    Total persons                           20193   0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    Total whose                             17215   0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    Under 15 years                          2179    0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    15 years                                1366    0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    16 years                                2369    0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    17 years                                1767    0       0
Carlow  2006    Male    18 years                                2485    0       0
```

In the second table

```
County  Year    Gender  EducStatu                                   EduCnt
Carlow  2006    Male    Total education ceased and not ceased       20193
Carlow  2006    Male    Total whose full-time education has ceased  17215
Carlow  2006    Male    Primary (incl. no formal education)         3536
Carlow  2006    Male    Lower secondary                             4408
```

Note : always less data In the second table
Result should look like this

County  Year    Gender  AgeDetails      EconStat    EducStatu               AgeCnt  EconCnt EduCnt
Carlow  2006    Male    Total persons       Total education ceased and not ceased   20193   0   20193
Carlow  2006    Male    Total whose         Total whose full-time education has ceased  17215   0   17215
Carlow  2006    Male    Under 15 years      Primary (incl. no formal education) 2179    0   3536
Carlow  2006    Male    15 years            Lower secondary         1366    0   4408
Carlow  2006    Male    16 years                            2369    0   0
Carlow  2006    Male    17 years                            1767    0   0
Carlow  2006    Male    18 years                            2485    0   0

Comment: can you share us some sample data, this will be helpful. like table data and your desired data

Comment: Well, if you don't have an explicit primary key (***why?!?!?!??***), then you must tell us *which columns* taken together uniquely identify each row (e.g. make up an "implied" primary key). If you cannot define anything like that, then you cannot possibly update this properly. ....

Comment: If both tables doesn't relate each other, then how can you update it?

Comment: sure.I will edit the question. thanks

Comment: I've edited your sample data so that it would show in correct format. I will not do it for your results as well. This time it's on you.

Comment: Thanks Zohar. Can you guide how to align the values to show like a table.

Comment: SO shows text in code mode when there is at least one blank row above it and 4 spaces before it. You can click on the edited x hours ago link to see the differences between the versions if you need a visualization.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of County, Year and Gender columns are not unique. In your sample data, they have the exact same set of values for all rows in both the columns. So you cannot do any operations based on them.

In your second column, you are left with two columns - EducStatu, and EduCnt. From the data, EducStatu is the column that differentiates rows in the second table (in addition to the combination of the first three columns in that table). But you have mentioned that EduStatu is blank in the first table. So you don't have any link (through columns) between the first and second tables. From the data you have given here, there is no way to pragmatically summarize the data in second table to meaningful data in the first table. Unless you have more columns in both tables, you are out of luck.

Comment: I hope there is another option with cursor. I am thinking in that way